# Java sftp file transfer for windows servers

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, sftp, file-transfer

My requirements is-
To push the file into windows servers  from other windows server. Files will be near 1000s of in 1 batch and it will run these batches  to sftp locations

So i need to config multithreads to process these files

Issues :

The first thing i m picking  list of files from source directory  and that list i am iterating which is getting iterated successfully  like all the thread picking the file separately  nothing is colliding.
Then i need to connect  with sftp...

Heres the question.
I need create a separate  session for each thread right? And also separate channels to.

Is Jsch.jar SFTPConnection work for windows server to?

And the third when i am multithreading  and going to call
Channelsftp.put(src,des) its not putting  some pipe closed some time no file sometime inderoutbound exception some times input stream is closed. How to config that if possible? Like connection is created for each thread when it comes to putting  the file into sftp location its not working

Please if u have any push condition let me for multi threading it will help

Comment: *So i need to config multithreads to process these files*  Why do you think multithreading makes processing files faster?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Why do you think it does not?

Comment: Though, the question is quite broad for Stack Overflow. Yes, you need separate session and channel for each thread. For your other problems, post new question with [mcve].

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  Because IO operations across a network are almost always going to be disk or network limited, and using multiple threads will usually have no performance improvement or in the case of spinning disks actually slow things down.  Using multiple threads across a network with a large bandwidth-delay product can help because a single TCP connection is limited over such a connection so multiple parallel connections in that case can help.  But in general multithreading IO only helps if your file system and disk system support parallel access and you know how to take advantage of that.

Comment: Yes indeed. The *"bandwidth-delay product"* is actually quite common problem with SFTP due to the nature of the protocol. Also SSH can be CPU-bound, what is another factor to consider. See https://serverfault.com/q/694062/168875#694063.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Are you trying to say that you've never seen attempts to blindly solve slow single-threaded IO operations by going to multiple threads?  Where the effort to use multiple threads didn't help at all?  Or maybe even hurt performance? My point was to get the questioner to think about this particular situation and not to blindly try multiple threads as a solution because that's all too likely to wind up as wasted effort.